# Can you query Azure DevOps ChangedDate for a date range

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

I am trying to use the Azure DevOps WIQL to pull a list of work items that have change during a particular date range.

I know that you can pull the work items from a certain date till today, but I want to be able to query a range. Doing something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [System.Id],
    [System.WorkItemType],
    [System.Title],
    [System.State],
    [System.AreaPath],
    [System.IterationPath]
FROM workitems
WHERE System.ChangedDate > '2022-06-10'
AND System.ChangedDate < '2022-06-11'
```

Will only pull back information if the last change was between those dates, not if any change was done between those dates. i.e. if I created a work item on the 2022-06-10, this query will pull it back, but if I edit it on the 2022-06-13 it will no longer pull back.

Is it possible to query between a date range, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you description, you could try to use the following date range to show items from last week in Azure DevOps.

```
Created Date < @StartOfWeek
Created Date > @StartOfWeek - 1
```

For more date ranges you could refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops#----macros

Comment: That would only give me the date it was created. What I was trying to do is get a list of work items that have changed between a range.

Comment: You could try to list the work items from the specific created date and make the changed date >= created date, but it's also the last update date.
     
 [System.CreatedDate] > '2022-06-10'
AND [System.ChangedDate] >= [System.CreatedDate]

Comment: Thanks, will do that and then add additional filtering on the next part of my script